# R cannot be Resolved To a Variable only in one line

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, facebook

My friend created an android application using `phonegap`, `jquery` and `facebook sdk` in eclipse. I wanted to run the application in my computer. So I imported the whole project into eclipse. I downloaded all the necessary APIs. Initially I got a lot of errors, but I solved most of them. 
Now I am stuck with just one error. And it is in the `src/com.facebook.android./FbDialog.java` file. One particular line

```
Drawable crossDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close);
```

gives the error R cannot be resolved to a variable.

I have gone through a lot of similar questions on this website as well as other websites. I have cleaned the project innumerable times. The R.java file builds successfully. Also, my friend is not getting any error when he runs the same project in his laptop. So I don't think there is any problem with the coding part. 
I am definitely missing some important setting or download. Please help. This one error is giving me a lot of headaches.
I am a new user her so cant upload a screenshot.

Comment: check the imports in FbDialog.java file. if android.R is imported change it to point to your projects R.java file.

Comment: Done that already. No change in the error.

Comment: I have cleaned and tried 1000 times. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. `res/drawable` folders (`ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`) must contain an image named `close`, if not add it. I doesn't really mater, in order to overcome the error, in which of them the file exist.

But in order to use resourses properly see the Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility)

2nd. File `FbDialog.java` must have an `import` of the `R.java` sometimes the R imports get mixed with clean & built and instead of `import your.package.com.R;` it is included the `import android.R;`

Depending on the dependency libraries or related projects of main project the `close` file resource may be a part of an other library in that case you will need `import that.package.com.R;`. So if it is part of Facebook SDK then you will need `import com.facebook.android.R;`

I hope you get the logic of how R imports work.

---

**Update:** Lets force it to work, change line to:

`Drawable crossDrawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(your.package.com.R.drawable.close);`

Comment: I have done the import.your.package.com.R and import com.facebook.android.R; but the error is still there. Also close image is there in all the folders ldpi,hdpi,and mdpi.

Comment: you do not have to write `your.package.com` but your package name!

Comment: i know. i know. have written my package name only. just to tell you that i have done that also. It did not work.

Comment: Open `R.java` is there at drawable any variable named `close` ? Also, you can try delete `gen` folder to force its recreation?

Comment: There was a variable named close in R.java. Also deleted the gen folder. Did a rebuild and clean, the gen folder was regenerated. But the error remains.

Comment: I updated my post, and add a solution/workaround... I still believe that there is a mix with the imports, but cannot make any guesses.